# SharePoint hosted app and SharePoint online list data synchronization

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-hosted-app, data, synchronisation

Is there is possible to provide **two way synchronization** between SharePoint Online List data and SharePoint hosted app list data?

If I added data in SharePoint hosted app list data then it should reflect in SharePoint online list data and vice versa.

Suggest some help

Comment: It is possible, but not out-of-the-box. To provide a proper answer I would like to know what you're trying to achieve. Why do you need two lists on Host-web and App-web to contain the same data? Why do you need to sync both ways and not just one way?

Comment: In some context (Like in Microsoft PowerApp) I am not able to get integration between Hosted app but working with Online. So I need mediator which can communicate with these two context.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your comment, but I can suggest the following two approaches: event receivers or workflows. You can either use workflows with the "Call web service" action on both lists so that when an item is created or updated in either list, then the other list is updated as well with the new or updated item. The same idea applies to event receivers that fire when an item is created and updated. The event receivers are actually better because they can  fire when items are deleted as well.

Comment: The biggest challenge here is that the list in the SP-Hosted App does not have a static URL because the App URL contains a dynamically App Instance ID.

Comment: Do you have any reference related to this question

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any reference, nor have I done something like this before. My suggestions were entirely based on what I would look at first if I were to setup a sync between two lists on different SharePoint websites.